# Problem with populating an unbound text box given the value of a Checkbox on a continuous sheet

Tags: ms-access

I have tried, setting the focus on the Haveparts text box. Tried running it as an expression, but I run out of characters in the expression in the unbound text box.

So there are 4 Checkboxes in the Record entry. The record entry show correctly when I make the check boxes visible. I.e. the parts have been ordered and arrived for example. but the Parts Arrived does not display in the checkbox.

`If Me![PartsOrdered] = True And Me![PartsBO] = False And Me![PartsArrived] = False And Me![PartsSupplied] = False Then     Me.HaveParts.Text = "Parts on Order"          ElseIf Me![PartsOrdered] = True And Me![PartsBO] = True And Me![PartsArrived] = False And Me![PartsSupplied] = False Then     Me.HaveParts.Text = "Parts BO"          ElseIf Me![PartsOrdered] = True And Me![PartsBO] = False And Me![PartsArrived] = True And Me![PartsSupplied] = False Then     Me.HaveParts.Text = "Parts Arrived"          ElseIf Me![PartsOrdered] = True And Me![PartsBO] = True And Me![PartsArrived] = True And Me![PartsSupplied] = False Then     Me.HaveParts.Text = "Parts Arrived"          ElseIf Me![PartsSupplied] = True Then     Me.HaveParts.Text = "Parts Supplied"     End If`

Comment: That's the VBA version?

Comment: Yes thats correct. It cuts the iif statement short if I try and use the iif statement in the textbox. I suspect there is a limit on the length of a expression.

Comment: I have written it in the afterupdate section of the specific textbox, as well as on opening of the form.

Comment: Apologies, I am a beginner.

Comment: add a code module to your database.  Then wrap the long if else statement to a public function, say CalculateHaveParts(PartsOrdered, PartsBO,...) inside the code module. Then set HaveParts control source to CalculateHaveParts(...)

Comment: You cannot have unbound controls in a continuous form. You need to create a text field in your table and bound the control. Then simply update the field for each record via a query.

Answer (score 0):

According to the original code, the `PartsOrdered` part is unnecessary (it's always TRUE) and can be omitted from IFs:

```
If Me![PartsOrdered] = True And Me![PartsBO] = False And Me![PartsArrived] = False And Me![PartsSupplied] = False Then
    Me.HaveParts.Text = "Parts on Order"          
ElseIf Me![PartsOrdered] = True And Me![PartsBO] = True And Me![PartsArrived] = False And Me![PartsSupplied] = False Then
    Me.HaveParts.Text = "Parts BO"          
ElseIf Me![PartsOrdered] = True And Me![PartsBO] = False And Me![PartsArrived] = True And Me![PartsSupplied] = False Then
    Me.HaveParts.Text = "Parts Arrived"          
ElseIf Me![PartsOrdered] = True And Me![PartsBO] = True And Me![PartsArrived] = True And Me![PartsSupplied] = False Then
    Me.HaveParts.Text = "Parts Arrived"          
ElseIf Me![PartsSupplied] = True Then     
    Me.HaveParts.Text = "Parts Supplied"     
End If
```

You can simplify the code:

```
DIM TXT AS STRING
IF PartsSupplied Then     
    TXT="Parts Supplied"     
ELSE
    IF NOT (PartsBO OR PartsArrived) Then
        TXT="Parts on Order" 
    ELSEIF PartsBO AND NOT PartsArrived Then
        TXT="Parts BO"
    ELSEIF PartsArrived AND NOT PartsBO Then
        TXT="Parts Arrived"
    ENDIF
ENDIF
HaveParts.Text=TXT
```

Now, it is easy to find which condition is not defined correctly.

Comment: Now every Record says "Parts on Order" in the HaveParts Textbox irrespective if that records PartsOrdered checkbox  is checked or not, and also irrespective of whether the other checkboxes are ticked or not. I don't seem to get different results for different records.

Comment: Thanks for assisting. Appreciated and I can see that this is a much shorter condensed version. But it is not returning any results that match the checkboxes that have been ticked (checked).

Comment: I do not know the exact logic of the choices, and could not post the formatted code in comments. So, I wrote it as an answer. Logically, if `PartsSupplied` is checked, the status of any other choice is irrelevant, as can be seen in the original code. In order to write the correct IF blocks, please provide the complete truth table for these 4 checkboxes (a total of 16 states).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the way a continues form works?

A text box (in fact any control) cannot be un-bound, and as you well found out, if you assign the value to one text box, then they ALL show that result.

However, what you can do is "bind" the control to a public function you place in the same form.

So, then we need a function in which you pass the check boxes from the current row of data, and it returns the text.

So, in the form, we could have a public function like this:

```
Public Function MyStatus(pOrdered As Boolean, _
                        pBO As Boolean, _
                        pSupplied As Boolean, _
                        pArrived As Boolean) As String

     
    If pSupplied Then
       MyStatus = "Parts Supplied"
    Else
        If Not (pBO Or pArrived) Then
        MyStatus = "Parts on Order"
         ElseIf pBO And Not (pArrived) Then
            MyStatus = "Parts BO"
         ElseIf PARRIVE And Not PBOT Then
            MyStatus = "Parts Arrived"
         End If
    End If
    

End Function
```

Now, drop in the text box, and make the data source of the text box this:

```
 =MyStatus([PartsOrdered],[],[PartsBO],[PartsSupplied], PartsArrived)
```

So, now that the text box is "bound" to a function, and thus it will display the correct results for each row.

Comment: Thanks alot. Really appreciated. Posted the answer. You definitely put me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the explanation. Really great. Now I have learnt what the Public Function () is for

```
Public Function MyStatus(PartsOrdered As Boolean, PartsBO As Boolean, PartsArrived As Boolean, PartsSupplied As Boolean) As String

     
    If PartsSupplied = True Then
       MyStatus = "Parts Supplied"
    Else
        If PartsOrdered = False And PartsArrived = False And PartsBO = False And PartsSupplied = False Then
        MyStatus = " "
         ElseIf PartsArrived = True And PartsSupplied = False Then
            MyStatus = "Parts Arrived"
         ElseIf PartsBO = True And PartsArrived = False And PartsSupplied = False Then
            MyStatus = "Parts BO"
        ElseIf PartsOrdered = True And PartsBO = False And PartsArrived = False And PartsSupplied = False Then
            MyStatus = "Parts Ordered"
         End If
    End If
    

End Function
```

and this is then what I placed in the control

```
=MyStatus([PartsOrdered];[PartsBO];[PartsArrived];[PartsSupplied])
```

Once again thanks for the help. Champion stuff..